# How to use colon correctly in a presentation

Tags: punctuation, colons

I would like to clearly understand how to use a colon in a presentation. I read that the colon `:` is used to add further information to the sentence. I wonder how to use it in a presentation to add extra points as a list. For example,

Gaussian model:

1. is flexible in high-dimension.
2. can be constructed easily.
3. have different dependence parameters for each pair of variables.

Is this a correct way to use the `colon` in my presentation? if not could someone please let me know why and what is the correct way to express the points?

Comment: This is perfectly fine.

Comment: This use of the colon to segue to a thought that flows from the previous one is relatively rare: you won't find it used much in magazines and newspapers, say, or in commercial texts or technical writing. You are most likely to encounter it in academic writing, for example in a journal article or book written by a historian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not correct according to "used to add further information to the sentence". The phrase "Gaussian model" is not a sentence.  You could correctly use a colon following a sentence, for example.

> The Gaussian model has several benefits:
>
> It is flexible in high dimension.

If you are offering a list of possible ending to a sentence, the no puctuation is needed.  Just check that each ending "works" grammatically.  (There is an error if you say "Gaussian model have different dependence...").

It might be easier just to make a list of noun phrases. Here you can use colon to introduce a list.

> Advantages of Gaussian model:
>
> - flexiblity in high dimension